# Deriving the ">" operator from the "<" operator

Tags: c++, operators

I am attempting to implement a `operator>()` function using only the `<`, `||` and `!` operators. I can do so using the `==` oparator, but I cannot figure out how to eliminate the case of one operand being equal to the other using only the three given operators. Here is how I have done it otherwise:

```
bool operator>(a, b){
    if(!(a < b) || !(a == b){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

So far the only possibility I have come up with that may work would be to somehow create a recursive function. Other than that, is there any other way in which this can be done?

Comment: `a < b` if and only if `b > a`, non?

Comment: Yeah, what Kerrek said

Comment: I cannot believe how simple that is and I never thought of it - I'm so ashamed with myself haha, merci!

Comment: @vsoftco if you are defining incompatible < and > operators you should just step back and define new functions with a sensible name. BTW it has nothing to do with symmetry of an operator: both < and > are antisymmetric when their arguments are not ==

Comment: @dfogni I take it back, it's not about symmetry, is about the fact that you may have incomparable relations, such as `a R b` but not `b R a`, where `R` is your binary relation. One example is [majorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization), in which case you may still want to define your symbol as `<`. But again, for numbers Kerrek's approach is perfect.

Comment: Technically, `a < b` if and only if `b >= a`, but in this case `!(a < b)` produces the same logic.

Comment: @mikeyq6 that is not the case. By your logic: "`a < b` if `b > a` or else if`b == a`"- of course, it is never ture that `a < b` if `b == a`.

Comment: I stand corrected. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a < b` if and only if `b > a` - as @Kerrek put it so simply above.

```
bool operator>(a, b){
    if(b < a){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Or even to further simplify, thanks to @Mokosha below

```
bool operator>(a, b){
    return b < a;
}
```

Comment: bool operator>(a, b) { return b < a; }

Answer (score 1):

Besides the obvious solution proposed by @KerrekSB (which is the best because of its simplicity), just as a curiosity you can also follow this approach from your code using the `XNOR` operator (note that it's not possible to do it using only the `||` operator, because for defining `XOR` you need both the `||` and the `&&` operators - more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Equivalencies.2C_elimination.2C_and_introduction)):

```
bool operator>(a, b){
    if(!(a < b) || !(x ^ y){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    } 
}
```